# Chrome Float Left Issue

Tags: html, asp.net, css, google-chrome

My chrome is the latest 31.0.1650.48 version.

Today I just notice that the float:left seems not working properly. (IE & FF are fine and Chrome used to be fine as well.)

Html is like:

```
<div class="listWrapper collapsed clearfix">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="aa"></a></li>
    <li><a href="" title ="bb"></a></li>
    <li><a href="" title ="cc"></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="ui-checkbox" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```

Css is like:

```
.ui-checkbox {
   background: url("../images/elements/form.png") no-repeat -183px -331px;
   width: 37px;
   height: 31px;
   float: left; 
}
```

What happened now is the inner checkbox **div** cannot float next to **ul** & **li** at very beginning. But if I right-click on that div --> Inspect Element --> Untick 'float: left' and then re-tick it on, it becomes correct.

Who has any idea about this?

**ADD:**

**ul** is float:left and each **li** actually has 1 background image and float:left as well. In that case, 3 (li) images show together in 1 line, and next div (checkbox shape) should display in the same line. But now **div** display to next line unless I untick & re-tick its float:left css.

**ADD AGAIN**

Please see the screen shots for 2 result:
[image]

The WHOLE div is float:right, and inner ul,li and div are float left. But the green "checkbox like" div at very beginning display under all these li. When I untick and re-tick float:left, it becomes OK.

Thanks!

Comment: any reason for having float:left and inline-block both?

Comment: Do you mind providing a screenshot of the output?

Comment: Ravi, some other page needs this "checkbox like" div show on the same line of a label. And even I remove this, it's the same.

Comment: use display:inline-block;

Comment: I also came here because Chrome 30 and Chrome 31 definitely display the float left differently. This seems like a big change in rendering indeed.

Comment: Yes. I tried in IE10, Firefox even Safari and they are all OK, except Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have given an explicit `width` to `<ul>`. And check whether your `<ul>` 's and the `checkbox div` 's widths' addition are ***less than or equal*** to the width of **div listWrapper collapsed**. If there is no width to the mother div then it is ok and try this

```
.ui-checkbox {
   background-color:green;
   width: 37px;
   height: 31px;
   float: left; 
}

ul{
    float: left;
    width:50px;
}
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scPHc/)

Or the update [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scPHc/1/).

Comment: Result is OK this time. Maybe because my li has image as background as well?

Comment: @Samuel Nah, background has nothing to do with this. May be the width of `listWrapper` isn't bigger the than the total width of `ul` and the `checkbox`div. Anyway is it working now? :)

Comment: Guru, listwrapper actually doesn't have width, and we just want it float right. Because the number of li displayed is dynamic, we couldn't set the fix width of listWrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're getting different results from different browsers, but you need to float the `ul` element as well to position the checkbox alongside it. Also, as someone mentioned in your post comments, you have an inline style changing the `display` property to `inline-block`, which obviously negates the float property.

[Here's a codepen.](http://codepen.io/erquhart/pen/wEtoC) I replaced the background image url with a color just to show the behavior.

Comment: I did, but that looks OK :( Maybe because my li use image as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-checkbox {
   background: url("../images/elements/form.png") no-repeat -183px -331px;
   width: 37px;
   height: 31px;
   float: left; 
   display:inline-block
}
```

Comment: That style is already getting applied by inline styling in HTML

Comment: I can do that but the result is the same :(